# How to use dyn package to perform regression on xts object?

Tags: r, xts, linear-regression

I've recently learn that there is a package call dyn which can perform regressions on xts object, however I have trouble reading the manual.

If there is a datum like below:

```
data(sample_matrix) 
#sample_matrix is a built-in datum in xts package

xtsObject=as.xts(sample_matrix)[,"Close"]  
#Extract daily close price to xtsObject
```

I tried the code below,but it gives me some error message.

```
dyn$lm(xtsObject~index(xtsObject))
```

Is this code correct? If not, how to do it?(I want to set xtsObject as dependent variable, time or date of datum as independent variables)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug but here is a workaround:

```
tt <- xts(time(xtsObject), time(xtsObject))
dyn$lm(xtsObject ~ tt)
```

Note that you can ask dyn questions on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqldf

Comment: Thanks for your help again. What does the time() do? Is it the same as index()?

Comment: Yes, `index` can be used here too.

Comment: object tt of above contains lots of numbers in it, do you know what those numbers mean?

Comment: POSIXct represents datetimes as seconds since the UNIX epoch and that is what `lm` uses when given a POSIXct object regardless of whether or not you use dyn.

Comment: So you mean it makes no difference whether I use dyn or not in this situation? Since they both use the seconds since UNIX epoch?

Comment: Yes.  This is the same: `xx <- coredata(xtsObject); tt <- time(xtsObject); lm(xx ~ tt)`.  dyn is usually used to automatically align lags and diffs.